# Creating list checker in Python. Compares lists and provides difference between them. Struggling with tail end of script

Tags: python, list

I am writing a short script that is suppose to look at a master list and a (for lack of better term) slave list, and output inconsistencies in the slave list when compared to the master list. I am very much a novice when it comes to coding..... Any insight would be much appreciated.

The data I'm trying to sort are in text files. Look something like the following:

```
12345678-Bananas

23456789-Apples

12345678-StarWars

23456789-RedBall

11223344-RedRover

22334455-Rabbit
```

I sort the data into lists (I think) using the follow bit of code:

```
    filename = utils.SelectOpenFile(0, "Text file (*.txt)")
    print (filename[0])
    if not filename[0]:
        return          
    text_file = open(filename[0], "r")  
    Part_List = text_file.read( ).splitlines( )

    PN_List = [ ]
    index = 0
    for line in Part_List:
        PN_List.append (Part_List[index][:8])
        PN_List[index] = PN_List[index].lower( )
        index += 1

    List1 = sorted(list(Counter(PN_List).items( )))
```

Which nets me:

```
List1 = [('12345678',2),('23456789',2),('11223344',1),('22334455',1)]
```

then compare it to another list that will either be identical or slightly different, like so:

```
List2 = [('12345678',3),('23456789',1),('11223344',1)]
```

I'm trying to see if List2 matches the "master" List1. What I would like as an output would be:

```
List3 = [('12345678',-1),('23456789',1),('22334455',1)]
```

So far have tried the following:

```
    for x in List2:
        if x[0] in List1:
            if x[1] < x[1] in List1:
                print ("Too Few Parts")
            elif x[1] > x[1] in List1:
                print ("Too Many Parts")
            else:
                print ("Perfecto")
        else:
            print ("Extra Part")
    for y in List1:
        if y[0] in List2:
            return
        else:
            print ("Missing Part")
```

open to better solutions

Comment: I've also tried Counter(PN_List) - Counter(Part_List) but it just prints "Counter()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that

```
List1 = [('12345678',2),('23456789',2),('11223344',1),('22334455',1)]
```

represents a set of part numbers and a quantity on hand. You are finding this difficult because your data structure doesn't match the problem you are trying to solve. Convert the master list to a dictionary:

```
>>> master = dict(List1)
>>> master
{'12345678': 2, '23456789': 2, '11223344': 1, '22334455': 1}
```

and do the same with the slave list:

```
>>> slave = dict(List2)
```

Now you will have a much easier time of matching up the part numbers.

```
>>> result = master.copy()
>>> for k,v in slave.items():
        if k in master:
            result[k] -= v
        else:
            print (f"Missing part {k}")
```

Now convert the resulting dictionary back to a list of *(part-number, quantity)* tuples. You could just do `List3 = list(result.items())` but it appears you want to drop a part number from the master list if the quantity goes to zero.

```
>>> List3 = [(k,v) for (k,v) in result.items() if v != 0]
>>> List3
[('12345678', -1), ('23456789', 1), ('22334455', 1)]
```

You can use `Counter` for this too, but first you need to do it the hard way so that you understand what `Counter` is doing. The solution is identical. The only difference is that `Counter` does the subtracting for you in one function call.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c1 = Counter(dict(List1))
>>> c2 = Counter(dict(List2))
>>> c3=c1.copy()
>>> c3.subtract(c2)
>>> c3
Counter({'23456789': 1, '22334455': 1, '11223344': 0, '12345678': -1})
>>> List3 = [(k,v) for (k,v) in c3.items() if v != 0]
>>> List3
[('12345678', -1), ('23456789', 1), ('22334455', 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks! The dict() changed everything.